# Can I run Skyrim on Mac with Bootcamp with my machine?

Tags: macos, mac, memory, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

Here's the situation:

I've tried running Skyrim on my Mac using a demo of Crossover 13.2.

My Mac looks like this:

V 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)
2.93 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
4GB 1067 MHz DDR3
NVIDIA GeForce 120
VRAM: 256 MB

Not the most impressive thing, but these were the results:

I managed to get through the whole "Unbounded" quest (the first "level" of the game) on Low settings without trouble, and it didn't look too bad considering the low settings. Now out in the open world however, it only takes a few minutes of running, particularly to a river, for it to irreparably freeze. (I've tried it many times) The music and sound go on as normal, but video is completely frozen. The only way out is to force quit, no error report follows.

Is there any reason to believe that the game would run much better if I partitioned my Mac with Bootcamp and ran it on that? Might that solve the freezing problem? The Windows XP OS is too expensive to buy without knowing if it will help matters, this is why I seek advice.

If the answer is that it has little or no hope of running well even with Bootcamp, is there anything else I can do (aside from buying a PC or game console) to fix that? (increase RAM? get a different video card... etc)

Thank you, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Why would you pick XP to run within a bootcamp, its unsupported, pick Windows 7 or newer but yes bootcamp makes it run as native instead of an emulator or virtual machine but your problem is the fact your hardware is below even the min specifications even if you use bootcamp the game will still crash because of your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!

I thought of trying XP because it was the only one I found with SP2 on Amazon, it was listed by my version of Bootcamp as the recommended OS along with Vista, and it has been listed as compatible with Skyrim on various websites including this one: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:System_Requirements

Is there anything I can do to bring the hardware up to at least minimum requirements using my current machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would experience better performance by running it in a Boot Camp partition.

However, given your video card, I doubt you will have a good chance at running Skyrim smoothly. The requirements on your link state VRAM to be at least 512MB, which your card doesn't have.

Purchasing a newer stock NVIDIA Graphics card after updating your Mac to a newer version of OS X (10.8+) is what I would recommend. See this link: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1440150

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you would have a better experience using a Wineskin port on your Mac but, unfortunately, your VRAM isn't enough to run Skyrim (which requires 512Mb). If someday you buy a new Mac, I recommend that Skyrim port:

> http://portingteam.com/files/file/7782-skyrim-wineskin-updated-2014/

In order to run different games, you can use Porting Kit or try PaulTheTall wrappers:

> http://portingkit.com/
>
> http://paulthetall.com/

Good luck.

Comment: Now Skyrim is also available in Porting Kit database :)